# How to fetch the status of Internet security setting(Display mixed content) using javascript or c# code

Tags: javascript, security, setting

Is there any way to detect the internet security setting using javascript or through C# code

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on Browser and OS how you can do this and most of all, if you like to do it from within the browser or not.
You can do it for example for Windows/IE using JScript. But ususally not within the browser, because you will have to read the registry.